I want to make, Flutter non-removable notifications
Flutter non-removable notifications
if user want to remove then visible the dismiss button I want. just like flipkart notification functionality.
I tried but didn't work any method after android 14 upgrade!
please give the feedback if your have any idea regard notification.

Have you tried to show notification with snackbar? It has property isDismissible which can be set to false.

From android 14 onwards the behaviour has been changed.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications
